# How to get list of items from Gsheets to a form dropdown based on value?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a sheet that collects details about our audit staffs expense submission details over Google Sheets which is logged via a Form.

I want to automate the task of there being less interactions with them over email correspondence by having another Admin approve their expenses.

For this, I have a sheet set up within the expense submission sheet that the Admin can approve based on the unique identifiers given to each submission that picks those identifiers and populates them in the form that admin has to approve. Unfortunately, I only need those references that have been either rejected or are open for approval.

How do I put a condition of picking the reference from column 2, the condition for which exists in column 7?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could do it.  This will also display the list as a dialog.

```
function getRejectedAndOpen(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Expense Submission');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var rA=[];
  var html='<style>th,td{border:1px solid #000;}</style><table><tr><th>References</th><th>Condition</th></tr>';
  for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++){//Assume one header row
    if(vA[i][6]=="open for Approval" || vA[i][6]=="Reject"){
      rA.push([vA[i][1],vA[i][6]]);//collecting column 2 and column 7
      html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>',vA[i][1],vA[i][6]);
    }
  }
  html+='</table>';
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'The List');//This will display your list as a modeless dialog.
  return rA;
}
```